# AWK print non-blank columns from CSV (and include header row)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

All,

I'm parsing a CSV line-by-line and creating a table for each line but I only want to print the column and header for non-blank fields.
Sample data:

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
field1,,field3,field4
```

I want:

```
HEADER1,HEADER3,HEADER4
field1,field3,field4
```

Comment: "I know there's a easy way to do this with awk" , Then edit your Q to show us what you've tried. S.O. isn't a free coding service, you're expected to show your work, and then we can help correct any conceptual problems you may have about how the code is (not) working. Good luck.

Comment: Is it always just one header and one record?

Comment: Yeah, just working with one line at a time as I'm essentially looping through the file line-by-line to create a table out of each.

Comment: this smells like a X-Y problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  If you present your actual problem, not the attempted solution you'll get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script like this (blanks.awk):

```
BEGIN   { FS=OFS=","}
NR == 1 { for ( i = 1; i<= NF; i++ ) hdrs[ i ] = $i
          next
        }
1       { for( i =1; i <= NF; i++){
            printf("%s", ($i!="" ? hdrs[ i ] OFS: "") )
          }
          printf("\n")
          for( i =1; i <= NF; i++){
            printf("%s", ($i!="" ? $i OFS: "") )
          }
          printf("\n")
        }
```

With blanks.csv being your file, run this command: `awk -f blanks.awk blanks.csv`

Comment: Works great! Thank you! I can edit as needed to do it line by line. Much appreciated Lars.